# Create programatically message-driven-channel-adapter to process the messages on queue

Tags: spring-integration

I would like process the message programmatically using message-driven-channel-adapter. Here is scenario which I have to implement:
My application during the startup read the configuration from a service. The configuration provides information about the queues which will contain the messages. Hence I would like to create a message-driven-channel-adapter for each queue to listen to messages asynchronously.

Any example which initializes all the spring integration context programatically instead of using XML will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to do everything programmatically, I'd suggest you bypass Spring Integration magic and just use `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` directly.

Afterwards you can send messages to an existing `MessageChannel` directly from the `MessageListener` implementation or using Messaging Gateway.

Please, be careful with programmatic configuration with that do not miss important attributes like `ApplicationContext` or invocation for `afterPropertiesSet()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It made sense, I have my POC in working condition.